# How can I put the number of page at top and center of page without header

Tags: header-footer

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\\Committee Decision}
\begin{center} \fontsize{14}{10}\selectfont


    \thispagestyle{headings}

%   \Large\textbf{ Committee Decision}
%   \\
%   \bigskip
    \textbf{\large Computer Simulation Of Slowly Varying Functions Adapted to Physics Problem}
    \\
    \bigskip
    \textbf{by}
    \\
    \centering \textbf{\large Aalaa Emad Abu Alrob}
    \\
    \bigskip

\end{center}
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more context, because there are a large number of ways this can be achieved. Why not use the `headings` page style to put the page number at the top?

Comment: oh i misunderstanding you i dont want  a line on the top of page

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, working example that replicates your current setup. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) It'll allow the community to see exactly what you're seeing without having to guess what's going on. In particular, your definition of the `headings` page style is important. Having a piece of code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` avoids misunderstanding. Can you do that?